# Why my estimated negative log likelihood loss is constant for all the input images

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, anomaly-detection

I am trying to learn the manifold of a particular class (say digit 1 for the MNIST dataset) using the latent space density estimation. I am using a Gaussian model (Mixture Density Network, MDN) to estimate the densities of the latent space (obtained through an autoencoder). I am using a neural network to approximate mean and variance for the MDN.

I facing a problem that, all of my estimated densities and consequently the negative log-likelihood loss is coming constant. This can be true for learning the manifold of digit 1 (although there should be some variance) but should be constant while testing it with the other digits.

Below you can see the loss plot for the learned class (normal class) and the new class (anomaly class)

Below is the code for the MDN and MDn loss estimation -

```
import sys
import torch
import warnings
import numpy as np
import torch.nn as nn
import seaborn as sns
import torch.optim as optim
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.autograd import Variable
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from scipy import ndimage
#from hessian import hessian
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')


COEFS = 10
IN_DIM =32
OUT_DIM = IN_DIM

class MDN(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, input_dim=IN_DIM, out_dim=OUT_DIM, layer_size=10, coefs=COEFS, test = False, sd =0.2):
        super(MDN, self).__init__()
        self.fc = nn.Linear(input_dim, layer_size)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(layer_size, layer_size)
        self.pi = nn.Linear(layer_size, coefs)
        self.mu = nn.Linear(layer_size, out_dim*coefs) # mean
#        self.mu = nn.Linear(layer_size, coefs) # mean
        self.sigma_sq = nn.Linear(layer_size, coefs*out_dim) # isotropic independent variance
        self.out_dim = out_dim
        self.coefs = coefs
        self.test = test
        self.sd = sd

    def forward(self, x):        

        if self.test:
            y = x
        else:
            ## Adding Noise ##
            y = add_noise(x, noise_type="gaussian", sd =self.sd)
#            y =x

        ## Learning ditribution parameters ##
        for i in range(x.size(0)):
            x = F.leaky_relu(self.fc(y[i]))
            x = F.leaky_relu(self.fc2(x))
            pi = F.softmax(self.pi(x), dim=-1)
            sigma_sq = F.softplus(self.sigma_sq(x).view(self.coefs,-1)) #logvar
            mu = self.mu(x).view(self.coefs,-1) #mean
        return pi, mu, sigma_sq


'''
    functions to compute the log-likelihood of data according to a gaussian mixture model.
    All the computations are done with log because exp will lead to numerical underflow errors.
'''

def log_gaussian(x, mean, logvar):
    '''
    Computes the Gaussian log-likelihoods

    Parameters:
        x: [samples,features]  data samples
        mean: [features]  Gaussian mean (in a features-dimensional space)
        logvar: [features]  the logarithm of variances [no linear dependance hypotesis: we assume one variance per dimension]

    Returns:
         [samples]   log-likelihood of each sample
    '''
    a = (x - mean) ** 2  # works on multiple samples thanks to tensor broadcasting
    log_p = (logvar + a / logvar.exp()).sum(-1)
    log_p = -0.5 * ( np.log(2 * np.pi) + log_p )
#    log_p = -0.5 * log_p  #forgetting constants
    return log_p

def log_gmm(x, means, logvars, weights, total=True):
    '''
    Computes the Gaussian Mixture Model log-likelihoods

    Parameters:
        x: [samples,features]  data samples
        means:  [K,features]   means for K Gaussians
        logvars: [K,features]  logarithm of variances for K Gaussians  [no linear dependance hypotesis: we assume one variance per dimension]
        weights: [K]  the weights of each Gaussian
        total:   wether to sum the probabilities of each Gaussian or not (see returning value)

    Returns:
        [samples]  if total=True. Log-likelihood of each sample
        [K,samples] if total=False. Log-likelihood of each sample for each model

    '''
    res = log_gaussian(
            x[None,:,:],  # (1,examples,features)
            means[:,None,:],  # (K,1,features)
            logvars[:,None,:] # (K,1,features)
    )
    # res is (K,examples)
    res = weights[:,None] * res

    if total:
        return res.sum(0)
    else:
        return res

# for Mishra
def mdn_loss_function(x, means, logvars, weights, test = False):
    if test:
        res = -log_gmm(x, means, logvars, weights)
    else:
        res = torch.mean(-log_gmm(x, means, logvars, weights))
    return res


def loss_fn(y, pi, mu, sigma_sq, model, sd =0.2, test = False):
    loss1 = mdn_loss_function(y, mu,sigma_sq, pi, test = test)
    if test:
        return loss1
    else:

    #    hes = hessian(loss1, model.parameters(), out=h)
        hes = torch.tensor(ndimage.filters.laplace(y.detach().cpu().numpy())).cuda()
    #    print(f"hessian : {hes}")

        loss = loss1 + 0.5*(torch.tensor(sd)**2)*torch.sum(hes)
        return loss





##### Adding Noise ############

def add_noise(latent, noise_type="gaussian", sd =0.2):
    """Here we add noise to the latent features concatenated from the 4 autoencoders.
    Arguments:
    'gaussian' (string): Gaussian-distributed additive noise.
    'speckle' (string) : Multiplicative noise using out = image + n*image, where n is uniform noise with specified mean & variance.
    'sd' (integer) : standard deviation used for generating noise

    Input :
        latent : numpy array or cuda tensor.

    Output: 
        Array: Noise added input, can be np array or cuda tnesor.
    """
    assert sd >= 0.0
    if noise_type=="gaussian":
        mean=0.

        n = torch.distributions.Normal(torch.tensor([mean]), torch.tensor([sd]))
        noise = n.sample(latent.size()).squeeze(2).cuda()
        latent = latent + noise
        return latent

    if noise_type=="speckle":
        noise = torch.randn(latent.size()).cuda()
        latent = latent + latent*noise
        return latent
```

[image: Loss plot showing reconstruction loss and likelihood loss for the normal and the anomaly class. The problem is **why the likelihood loss constant for both normal and anomaly class**]

Comment: Not sure if this is your entire issue, but you cannot run `torch.tensor(ndimage.filters.laplace(y.detach().cpu().numpy())).cuda()` where you detach the tensor from `device`, do an operation, and then place back on `device` and then run `.backward()` on the loss because you are breaking the graph